# Print SubArray of Maximum Contiguous product in Array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Maximum Product Subarray
Given an array that contains both positive and negative integers, find the subarray of the maximum product .
Examples:

Input: arr[] = {6, -3, -10, 0, 2}
Output:  The subarray is {6, -3, -10}

Input: arr[] = {-1, -3, -10, 0, 60}
Output:  The subarray is {60}

Input: arr[] = {-2, -3, 0, -2, -40}
Output:  The subarray is {-2, -40}

Note: Finding the Max Product is done as using the kadane algo where i tried to reuse it for finding sub array but not able to break the part of finding the start index, finding end index is easy. end index is where res  < max.

```
public int maxProductSubArray(int arr[], int len) {

        int res = arr[0];

        int max = arr[0];
        int min = arr[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {

            int temp = max;

            max = Math.max(Math.max(max * arr[i], min * arr[i]), arr[i]);
            min = Math.min(Math.min(temp * arr[i], min * arr[i]), arr[i]);

            res = Math.max(res, max);
        }

        return res;

    }
```

but not able to break the problem to find the SubArray.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Can you suggest what is wrong in what i posted and where i missed ? it is clear by tags and problem statement. And yes i did search stack and google before posting this question.

Comment: Number #3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: did i do anything wrong ? or did i miss anything in post ?

Comment: now i got your point . Have edited and put the things i tried and where i was stuck

Comment: It's not clear why do you need `min` here, after all, you're looking for the max, no?

Comment: it is a product , so min multiplied with negative number will result in max e.g. -900 * -1 can be max as 900.

Comment: I think the following link is what you are searching for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subarray/, but in this form, it will not return the subarray, but only its product.

Comment: @vulpini99 that solves only finding max product, but my problem statement is to find sub array. Your solution is working but it is in O(n3).

Comment: Do you have to use kadane or is it just a suggestion?

Comment: just suggestion.

Comment: Please have a look at the solution provided at the link above. You will have to make only small changes to reach your goal.

Comment: is there way to reach it by optimized method, exp kadan algo. i am not able to find the case where to put start index.

Comment: I suggest starting a new question on that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible ways to solve this problem:

- Brute-Force
- Divide-and-Conquer
- Backtracking

I will only show you the Brute-Force-Solution. It is not the fastest solution, but in my opinion the most clear and easily understandable solution:

```
public class SubArray {

    public static int findMax(int[] num) {

        int max = num[0];
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {   //Iterating over every possible starting position
            for(int j = i; j < num.length; j++) { //Iterating over every possible end position
                int multiply = 1;
                for(int k = i; k <= j; k++) {   //Multiply from start to end
                    multiply *= num[k];
                }
                if(max < multiply) {    //Did we find a new maximum?
                    max = multiply;
                    start = i;
                    end = j;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("The subarray is {");  //Print subarray with highest product
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(num[i]);
            if(i < end) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("}");

        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {6, -3, -10, 0, 2} ;
        int max = findMax(array);
        System.out.println("Maximal product is: " + max);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be efficiently solved by divide and conquer.

Assume you want to solve the problem for a subarray `[l, r]`; Then, assuming `c = (l + r) / 2` the solution is either subarray in `[l, c]`, or in `[c + 1, r]`, or in some subarray containing `c` and `c + 1`.

Then let's define a function `f(l, r)` returning the answer for subsegment; Then, to compute this function, first recursively call `f(l, c)` and `f(c + 1, r)` and pick the maximum as the temporary answer. Then compute multiplications of segments `[c, c]`, then `[c - 1, c]` and so on (using `multiplication of [c - k, c] = multiplication of [c - k + 1, c] * array[c - k]`) and compute maximum and minimum multiplications across all such segments. Do the same for segments to the right of `c` (`[c + 1, c + 1]`, `[c + 1, c + 2]` and so on) Then, the answer will be either a temporary answer, of multiplication of maximums or multiplication of minimums or multiplication of minimum and maximum and vice versa (minimum times maximum is required if such multiplication would be negative). Return the maximum across these four values or the temporary answer as the function result.

If it is necessary, instead of returning just the value of multiplication function can also return the segment where these value is reached.

This solution uses `Θ(n log n)` time and `Θ(n)` space.